# Issues with replaying music in Android Media Player

Tags: android, media-player

To start off, playing and stopping music works fine. I've already searched SX, and have tried some of the solutions listed for this issue, but they haven't resolved my issue.

I have a "Replay Music" button, that is supposed to restart an .mp3 file from the beginning. I've got the necessary code in place (like reset(), prepare(), etc, in order for the media player to replay the music, but when the button is pushed, nothing happens.

I have all the OnClickListeners and other necessary things setup, it is just this one issue.

Below is the complete code for my "Replay Music" method. Any help will be gratefully received.

Just a thought: Perhaps it is something to do with the placement of the mediaPlayer.start() method call?

```
public void replaySoundButtonListener() {
    Button testButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.replayMusicButton);
    testButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

@Override   
public void onClick(View arg0) {

   mediaPlayer.reset();
   try {
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource("sdcard/InsomniMusic/insomnimix.mp3");
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }      
try {
    mediaPlayer.prepare();
} catch (IllegalStateException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
   mediaPlayer.start();     
}   
    });
}
```

Comment: This says call stop(), then prepare(), then start() again. You shouldn't need to call reset() nor set the datasource again: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11533728/using-mediaplayer-to-replay-the-same-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to prepare and set the data source of a mediaplayer once. When you call reset the mediaplayer has to be reinitialised completely (set datasource again and call prepare). If you would like to reset the mediaplayer to the start of the song I guess you could use

```
mediaPlayer.setOnSeekCompleteListener(new MediaPlayer.OnSeekCompleteListener() {
    @Override
    public void onSeekComplete(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }
});
```

If the song has already ended (or stopped otherwise), only `mediaPlayer.start()` will suffice (but I guess in your case you can never be sure of that).

More information on the start function [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#start%28%29)

Comment: Hi Gerard, so, all I actually need to do in that method is to have mediaPlayer.start()? (As I've included an on-screen instruction for the user to first stop the song, and *then* use the replay button), just so you know. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Well its not too clear from your code if it is possible to restart the song during playback? If it is, you should first seek to the start of the song. If it is not possible (you can only restart a song that has finished) then yes this should be enough!

Comment: I should also add that I get the infamous issue, whereby, if you stop a playing, and then (attempt) to start it again, no sound is heard, which is why I had what I had in the code above. You *could* restart the song during playback, that is up to the user. I'm not in the habit of taking control away from the user.

Comment: Yes try what I said above. I did discover one caveat when using seekTo, you need a listener to check when it is finished ill update the answer.

Comment: Just so I understand correctly, you want me to put both seekTo and start in my replay song method? Did you get that bit about the song playing the first time, but not the second (after it is stopped, and the "Play" button is pushed once more)?

Comment: Yes, just try it. Try simply start first if you like when the song has ended and later you can also try the other one. And maybe add some isPlaying() check to differentiate.

Comment: I just had the song end by itself, and I tapped the "Replay Sound" button. It worked! Thanks very much. Before I mark the answer as accepted though, would you be able to provide me with a snippet of code that if the number of milliseconds is greater than zero, then, pressing the "Replay Sound" button, will automatically cause the song to start at the beginning, please?

Comment: Glad it worked. I dont think you can easily get the milliseconds passed but you can get the current position `mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition()` and see if is greater than zero.

Comment: Thanks Gerard, I'll try that, and give it a go. Any thoughts on why, once I push the "Stop Music" button, and then the "Play Music" button, no music is heard, when, on app startup (the first time, in other words), the music was able to be heard, and how I could fix this 'error'?

Comment: Sorry no, not really. Is the error still present after the new code? You might want to try search on SO for this issue and possibly open another question about this issue. Good luck! (Also please accept the answer if it satisfies your current issue)

Answer (score 1):

```
  I made a functions to start() stop() reset() and pause() in another Class

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.media.MediaPlayer;

    public class AudioPlayer extends MediaPlayer {
        private MediaPlayer mPlayer;

        public void stop()
        {
            if(mPlayer!=null)
            {
                mPlayer.release();
                mPlayer=null;
            }
        }
        public void pause()
        {       
            if(mPlayer.isPlaying())     {
                mPlayer.pause();
                    }
            else
            {
                mPlayer.start();
            }
        }

        public void reset(Context c)
        {
            stop();

            mPlayer=MediaPlayer.create(c, R.raw.one_small_step); //uzimamo .create(context,..) jer uzimamo iz res/raw lokalne datoteke

            mPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    stop(); 
                }
            });

            mPlayer.start();
        }


        public void play(Context c)
        {
            stop();

            mPlayer=MediaPlayer.create(c, R.raw.one_small_step);

            mPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    stop(); 
                }
            });

            mPlayer.start();
        }
    }

      //Here is my fragment

    private Button mPlayButton;
    private Button mStopButton;
    private Button mPauseButton;
    private Button mResetButton;
    private AudioPlayer mPlayer=new AudioPlayer();

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            View v=getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.fragment_hello_moon, container);

            mPlayButton=(Button)v.findViewById(R.id.hellomoon_playButton);
            mPlayButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    mPlayer.play(getActivity());
                }
            });
            mStopButton=(Button)v.findViewById(R.id.hellomoon_stopButton);
            mStopButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    mPlayer.stop(); 

                }
            });

            mPauseButton=(Button)v.findViewById(R.id.hellomoon_pauseButton);
            mPauseButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    mPlayer.pause();

                }
            });

            mResetButton=(Button)v.findViewById(R.id.hellomoon_resetButton);
            mResetButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(
                    ) {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    mPlayer.reset(getActivity());

                }
            });
            return v;
    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mPlayer.stop(); //Nakon sto je fragment unisten MediaPlayer nastavlja radit jer je na drugacijem Threadu pa treba pozvati Stop();

    }
```