# android play raw file

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I have an app that basically looks like a bomb, when user click on the numbers, it will make sounds with the following code

```
        final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.c4_click);
            mp.start();
```

which works fine, and then when the numbers has been fully entered, user will then click on a button which will create another sound with

```
    final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.c4_plant);
            mp.start();
```

so now, my problem is when this "c4" has been planted, and another user press on the numbers again, the sounds are gone. Am i suppose to somehow stop the mediaplayer first? or what am i supposed to do here?

**EDIT:**
i have changed the numbers click sound to this

```
  Button btn = (Button) view;
    if(mp != null){
        if(mp.isPlaying()){
            mp.stop();
            mp.release();
        }
        mp = null;
    }
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.c4_beep1);
    mp.start();
```

and the button click sound to this

```
            if(mp != null){
                if(mp.isPlaying()){
                    mp.stop();
                    mp.release();
                }
                mp = null;
            }
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.c4_plant);
            mp.start();
```

but it crashes after

**EDIT**: full class
[full code here](http://paste.ofcode.org/xJvA79zA3FxYDpx7aZ7haN)
my first android app, please don't mind about the programming style and such

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Mediaplayer to replay the same file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11533728/using-mediaplayer-to-replay-the-same-file)

Comment: i have tried to follow that post, but the problem still exists

Comment: then please update your code in the question showing the new code, after you tried what they suggested

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**On Number Click**

```
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.c4_click);
mp.start();
```

**On `Button` click use this code.**

```
if(mp != null){
   if(mp.isPlaying()){
      mp.stop();
      mp.release();
   }
   mp = null;
}
mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.c4_plant);
mp.start();
```

Comment: i have tried this way to do it, but the app crashes after doing it this way. Before i have all these .stop and .release stuff, it just didnt output any sounds, but it was still running fine

Comment: Sorry I didnt get you. Is my code working fine for you or not?? @benjiWong

Comment: i have the mediaplayer defined at the top with     `private MediaPlayer mp = null;`    and everytime when i need to create/play a new media sound i would do something like `mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.c4_beep1);`   not too sure if this is okay to do?

Comment: can you post your full class in your question. @benjiWong